# Trying to extract the $first document from collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, database

After piping various documents through the aggregate framework I finally have the resultant documents.

The problem now is that I only want the $first and $last document.

The final document looks like this (huge list):

```
            ...
            {
                    "_id" : "Kaila Deibler",
                    "count" : 406
            },
            {
                    "_id" : "Jessika Dagenais",
                    "count" : 406
            },
            {
                    "_id" : "Tamika Schildgen",
                    "count" : 404
            },
            ...
```

The mongo shell command that I used to produce the document is:
`db.talks.aggregate([{$project: {_id: 0, comments: "$comments"}}, {$unwind: "$comments"}, {$group: {_id: "$comments.author", count: {$sum: 1}}}, {$sort: {count: -1}}])`

But I only need the first and last document so I attempted something like this:
`db.talks.aggregate([{$project: {_id: 0, comments: "$comments"}}, {$unwind: "$comments"}, {$group: {_id: "$comments.author", count: {$sum: 1}}}, {$sort: {count: -1}}, {$first: "$_id"}])`

I tried other implementations but can't seem to figure out when/where to implement `$first` and `$last`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my own answer to this question:

`db.talks.aggregate([{$project: {_id: 0, comments: "$comments"}}, {$unwind: "$comments"}, {$group: {_id: "$comments.author", count: {$sum: 1}}}, {$sort: {count: -1}}, {$group: {_id: "$_id.comments.author", first: {$first: "$_id"}, last: {$last: "_id"}}}])`

Since I want to pull the first and last document after the sort I have to apply another `$group` with `$first` and `$last`.  The result:

```
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : null,
                        "first" : "Elizabet Kleine",
                        "last" : "Mariela Sherer"
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Note the `"_id" : null`.  Is this necessary?
If anyone has a better solution please share.

Comment: What do you want to appear in the "_id" field of the result?  It looks like you are trying to show the "comments.author" again (which would now be in the `$_id` field), but that doesn't make much sense in context.  You could give it an arbitrary name, like `{$group: {_id: "First_and_Last",...`.

Comment: Right, I forgot you can do that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`$first` and `$last` are aggregation functions in the `$group` pipeline, which means you need to use them inside the `$group` document.

```
db.talks.aggregate([{$project: {_id: 0, comments: "$comments"}}, {$unwind: "$comments"}, {$group: {_id: "$comments.author", count: {$sum: 1}, first: {$first:"$_id"}}}, {$sort: {count: -1}}])
```

Similarly for `$last`

You can find an example that shows this [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-examples/#largest-and-smallest-cities-by-state)

Comment: I have to sort after the first `$group` because I only want the highest and lowest counts.  The way you have it returns something like this: '{"_id" : "Tawana Oberg", "count" : 396, "first" : Tawana berg"}, { "_id" : "Mariela Sherer", "count" : 387, "first" : " Mariela Sherer"}'.  Note that the first is just a repeat of the `_id`.

Comment: I was about to suggest you `$group` up after the `$sort` but it appears you have already done that in the above.